# How we can mock or trigger window.onload method in unit test case using jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

Please find below code, i need to trigger load event so that my test function get execute

```
const test = () => {
    return true;
};

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    test();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the test environment is `jsdom` for jest, then you can trigger the `load` event by using [dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent)

E.g.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  console.log('load event triggered');
});

describe('71220140', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('load'));
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/71220140/index.test.ts
  71220140
    ✓ should pass (13 ms)

  console.log
    load event triggered

      at stackoverflow/71220140/index.test.ts:2:11

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.301 s
```